# How to integrate $exp(\frac{-\lambda}{x^2})\phi(x)$

Tags: calculus

$\int_a^b\exp(\frac{-\lambda}{x^2})\phi(x){\rm d}x$, where $a, b$ are any real nubmers or infinity and $\phi(x)$ is a smooth function.

Seems like I need to use Laplace's approximation method but I don't understand clearly how. So maybe there are any other ways to solve it.

Comment: $\exp(-\lambda/x^2)$ is not an analytic function, hence there might be some issues. To perform the substitution $x=\frac{1}{z}$ can solve them in some cases, but I am not able to give you an insightful solution without knowing more about $\phi$. What is the original problem, for instance?

Comment: I think I have no more information. What else do You need to know about ϕ?

Comment: Is is compact-supported? Is it analytic? Is it the Fourier transform of some known function?

Comment: I think yes for all. At least first two. Use whatever you need

Comment: A function cannot be analytic *and* compact-supported.

Comment: misunderstood. what if we dont know anything about that ?

Comment: Then the question makes little sense, being like *what is the integral of a generic function*?

Comment: But this is all I have. So what do You think should be added?

Comment: I think the original problem should be added, in order to realize what do you *really* need.